# Ansible, Using variables to modify hosts and ports

Tags: json, variables, ansible

I need to do a lot of changes in our HP switches ports. I like ansible because it is fast when changing the same things in a bunch of switches.
This time I nee to do the same change but in different ports in each switch.

basically, I need to do this:

```
int F14,F15,F16
no power
wr mem
```

Ports will be different by switch. So if I have a list like this:

```
SW-IT-CH-1  F1,F2,F3
SW-IT-CH-2 A3,A6,A9,A2
SW-IT-CH-5 C1,D4,E8,F19
```

Is there a way to create a variables file and use a playbook and execute all changes in one shot?

I have this playbook:

```
---
- name: Aruba Config Change
  hosts: '{{ hosts }}'
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
     ansible_network_os: aruba
     ansible_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
     ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.sshpass') }}"
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Add to NETWORK group
      ignore_errors: yes
      aruba_config:
          lines:
          - no power 
          parents: interface '{{ ports }}'
```

I was thinking to have a json file containing the variables (variables.json) like this

```
'{"hosts":"SW-IT-CH-1","ports":"F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19"}'
'{"hosts":"SW-IT-CH-2","ports":"F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19"}'
```

and run ansible like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "@variables.json"
```

but no success...

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

The typical inventory file can contain variables.

```
[SW]
 SW-IT-CH-3 hosts=SW-IT-CH-3 ports=F14,F15,F16,F17,F18
 SW-IT-CH-2 hosts=SW-IT-CH-2 ports=F14,F15,F16,F17,F18
```

there is no need of having a variables file.
Then just run the playbook including the inventory file:

```
 ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e hosts=SW -i /tmp/inventory.txt
```